# Kitsune Winter Bash 2020

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2020

**Kitsune** is defined [here](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/kitsune) as:

> Vote to reopen a question, and answer it when it gets reopened. Both
> actions must occur during Winter Bash.

Imagine you write an answer to a question (OP), the question gets closed in the process.

You self-delete your answer (which was posted before the question (OP) was closed)

The question is: The OP was reopened (**with a re-open vote of yourself**). If you *undelete your answer* or *write a new answer*, will it qualify to trigger **Kitsune** ? Or would these actions be considered against the rules?

Answer (score 5):

No, it will not. The answer needs to have been posted after the reopen event occurred (and per the guidance, you also need to have been one of the users who cast a reopen vote), not just undeleted. Undeleting the answer does not alter the post's creation date.

Comment: The OP was reopened (with a re-open vote of yourself) hence the challenge of this

Comment: The answer is still the same. You did not post it after the question was reopened.

Comment: and posting a new answer with improved content of the self-deleted answer? or should one just forget about it because of being involved earlier?

Comment: @Vickel that's frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

That won't give you the hat, because the timestamp of the answer will be still the original date when you did the answer.

Deleting an answer and writing a new one might trigger the hat, but this technique is frowned upon